# Hibernate: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish-4

I am attempting to deploy an application on a glassfish 4 server on my local machine. When I copy the .war file into the autodeploy directory, the glassfish log returns exceptions and the application does not appear in the list of applications, on the server's admin console. I've consulted with a local colleague on this and based on comparisons to working instances, we believe the traces from the Glassfish server, shown below, may have something to do with the cause:

Server Trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:264)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:913)
... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from null. Initial cause was null
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from null. Initial cause was null
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.util.HibernateUtil.loadAndCorrectConfiguration(HibernateUtil.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:93)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:102)
    ... 73 more
```

If a full stack trace is needed or any further info or edits are needed, let me know. Otherwise, I will await response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266359/java-lang-nullpointerexception-hibernate-used-with-ehcache

Comment: This question has no valid answer whatsoever and the author kept details to himself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

I mispelled the ehcache property, in the Glassfish server.

Lesson Learned. :)

Comment: Share the wisdom or get out.